# opengl invert framebuffer pixels

Tags: c, opengl, pixel, framebuffer

I was wondering was the best way to invert the color pixels in the frame buffer is. I know it's possible to do with `glReadPixels()` and `glDrawPixels()` but the performance hit of those calls is pretty big.

Basically, what I'm trying to do is have an inverted color cross-hair which is always visible no matter what's behind it. For instance, I'd have an arbitrary alpha mask bitmap or texture, have it render without depth test after the scene is drawn, and all the frame buffer pixels under the masked (full alpha) pixels of the texture would be inverted.

I've been trying to do this with a texture, but I'm getting some strange results, also all the blending options I still find confusing.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Give something like [this](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/openGL/jxglTracker.aspx) a try:

```
glEnable(GL_COLOR_LOGIC_OP);
glLogicOp(GL_XOR);
// render geometry
glDisable(GL_COLOR_LOGIC_OP);
```

Comment: This is the normal way of doing it.

Answer (score 2):

how about:

```
glEnable (GL_BLEND); 
glBlend (GL_ONE_MINUS_DST_COLOR, GL_ZERO);
```

Comment: glBlend should be glBlendFunc, no?